# delete old records when new are logged

Tags: sql-server

I want to delete old data when new is logged after some time.

For Example I have 'table1' and i log 20 different values.

```
Name | Value
 1A  | 15268
 2A  | 26857
 3A  | 56847
 ... |  ...
 20A | 36874
```

After let us say 60 seconds a new set of that same data is logged.
But instead of placing it under the old values it deletes them and replaces them with the new.

So not

```
Name | Value
 1A  | 15268
 2A  | 26857
 3A  | 56847
 ... |  ...
 20A | 36874
 1A  | 26587
 2A  | 6958
 3A  | 36587
 ... |  ...
 20A | 98754
```

but only

```
 1A  | 26587
 2A  | 6958
 3A  | 36587
 ... |  ...
 20A | 98754
```

Is this possible ?
Thank you.

Comment: Use an `UPDATE` statement instead? Don't think that you need to `INSERT` a new row and `DELETE` the existing; just `UPDATE` the existing row(s).

Comment: Or `DELETE` then `INSERT`?

Comment: How do I choose to update and not insert because my logging program inserts it automatically.

Comment: Update/Insert/Delete statement depends on your data.If Name is same in all new data-set as present in your table then you can go with Update statement.IF data is different in both set (Specifically Column Name ) then go for Truncate/Delete and insert.

Comment: You have to change in your logging program.

Comment: That is the problem I do not have this option so I was wondering If I could do it in SQL

Comment: In the case that you do not have access to the logging program, I would then advise to use a trigger that automatically `truncates` the table or `deletes` the records in the table **before** insert.

Comment: How do I get the Delete to happen before the data is logged in because a trigger happens AFTER INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE so my new data would also get deleted if I just put a DELETE FROM TABLE in my trigger.

Answer (score 0):

`Truncate` the old data and `insert` the new data in your table

```
Truncate table tableName --removes all the data in your table

insert into tableName (col1, col2 ...) --inserts data
values (val1, val2, ...)
```